# How can I manage proliferating, deeply nested type parameters?

Tags: generics, types, language-agnostic, type-parameter

I want to know how to manage large numbers of deeply nested type parameters. Code is Scala. Answers welcome in any language.

Consider some config objects

```
trait Source
case class File(path: String) extends Source
case class URL(url: String) extends Source

trait Format
case class CSV(delimiter: String) extends Format
case class JSON extends Format

case class Data(format: Format, source: Source)
```

but as is I'm limited in my type information e.g. I can't

```
def find_delimiter(config: Data) = config.format.delimiter
```

So, I parameterize

```
case class Data[F <: Format, S <: Source](format: F, source: S)
```

and I can now specify I'm working with CSV

```
def find_delimiter[S <: Source](config: Data[CSV, S]) = config.format.delimiter
```

All is good. But if my config objects are not one but four layers deep, and my config objects have much longer names, we can end up with something like

```
def fn(config: DataSourceConfig[
  CSVConfig[ColumnDataTypeConfig[DeeplyNestedConfig[SuperDeeplyNestedConfig], OtherDeeplyNestedConfig]],
  URLConfig[FetchRetryConfig[HTTPDeeplyNestedConfig]]
]) = ???  // use deeply nested attributes here
```

which is a mess to read, and I went light on the parameters. How can I manage this?

Afaict, type aliases are impractical as they'd proliferate.